# How to restrict user to check only 5 check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 50 options but the user must select a maximum of 5 check boxes.

How could I restrict the user to select up to 5 check boxes?

Comment: show what have you tried

Comment: When any of checkboxes changes, count the number of checked checkboxes, and if there are 5 or more - disable all unchecked checkboxes; enable all checkboxes if there are less than 5. This sentence is almost the working code, just change its syntax to JS. Go ahead! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a common if statement like so:

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 5) {
    alert('exceed 5')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('input:checkbox:checked').length`

**Example**

```
  var total = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
  if (total <= 5) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```